# Regarding Android studio, how do you display the built in class files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there's some way to do this because i've done it by accident, I just don't know the proper terminology to use in a google/SO search, so my apologies. For instance: the View class, a built in Android class, how can I bring up the file inside Android Studio with all the methods etc to see how the class works? and yes I'm aware I can just go to android.developer.com and see everything, but thats not my question.

Comment: Use CTRL+(click on the class definition), it brings you to the class source if you have downloaded them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about going to the class declaration.  On Mac you can hold down Command and click on the class you want to go to, for Windows and Linux you can hold Control and click on the class.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html